# Salvando dados dinâmicos na mesma entitidade Java

Tags: java, jpa, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Estou usando Spring MVC, thymeleaf e para mim com todas as rotas construidas ele fazia automático mas não esta funcionando, entity, repository, controller e etc.

Tenho uma relação de N=N de curso para Turno, dessa relação criou a tabela cursoTurno os campos dor turno e inseridos direto no banco de dados e já esta listando no *front-end*. O problema e é na tabela cursoTurno e tem apenas o id de curso e turno tem um Atributo Quantidade de Vagas "QuantidadeVagas" e os valores são cadastrados através do formulário de curso. e um atributo dentro de um objeto dentro de outro objeto. Os campo do objeto curso esto salvando beleza na tabela curso mas os campos da outra tabela além de serem múltiplos valares podem ser salvos n esta salvando na tabela cursoTurno.

Códigos do *entity* e o formulário no *front-end* a o campo de validação de nulo estão com mesmo valor e estou resolvendo esse erro, pois buscar através de curso.cursoTurno.quantidadeVagas o thymeleaf não esta aceitando 2 objetos.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "curso")
public class Curso implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "curso_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "curso_id_seq", sequenceName = "curso_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "tipo_curso")
private TipoCursoEnum tipoCurso;

@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "nome")
private String nome;

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "situacao")
private SituacaoEnum situacao = SituacaoEnum.ATIVO;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "curso")
private List<CursoTurno> cursoTurno;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "unidade_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Unidade unidade;
```

Os getters e setters estão definidos para CursoTurno:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "curso_turno")
public class CursoTurno implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "curso_turno_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "curso_turno_id_seq", sequenceName = "curso_turno_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "curso_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Curso curso;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "quantidade_vagas")
private int quantidadeVagas;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "turno_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Turno turno;
```

Formulário javascript para adicionar e remover está funcionando:

```
<div class="row" >
    <!-- INICIO - Adiciona quantidade vagas -->
    <div id="curso-vagas-container">
        <div class="curso-vagas-item">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('cursoTurno')} ? has-error">
                    <label class="control-label required" for="quantidadeVagas" th:text="#{quantidadeVagas}">Quantidade de Vagas</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantidadeVagas" th:field="*{cursoTurno}" maxlength="50" />
                    <label class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cursoTurno')}" th:errors="*{cursoTurno}"></label>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('cursoTurno')} ? has-error">
                <label class="control-label required" for="turno" th:text="#{turno}">Turno</label>
                <select  class="form-control populate" id="turno" th:field="*{cursoTurno}" data-plugin-selectTwo="">
                    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
                    <option th:each="turno : ${listaTurnos}" th:value="${turno.id}" th:text="${turno.nome}"></option>
                </select>

                <label class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cursoTurno')}" th:errors="*{cursoTurno}"></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="remove-vaga-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
    <a class="btn btn-primary padding-buttons" role="button" id="btnAddCurso">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" style="color: white;"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Está bem dinâmico posso adicionar ou remover múltiplos e o contador está validando também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está difícil de entender qual a dúvida. Sugiro deixar mais claro qual a questão, além de ajustar acentuações e ortografia.

Comment: ortografia foi por preguiça msm, resumir tudo e que minha duvida é salvar no banco na tabela relacionada no caso OneToMany curso com cursoTurno